# How to hide css style of decandant span when parent div has text-overflow : ellipsis

Tags: html, css

I have a span with a different `background-color` which is shown although the parent `span` has a `text-overflow : ellipsis`:

```css
.container {
  border        : 1px solid black;
  max-width     : 100px;
  overflow      : hidden;
  text-overflow : ellipsis;
  white-space   : nowrap;
}

.backgroundColor {
  background-color : green;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    Lorem ipsum
    <span class="backgroundColor">should not be visible</span>
</div>
```

I do not want to see the green background of the decandent `span`... Now I am wondering, how can I prevent such behaviour e. g. achieve my goal?

Comment: Remove the `background-color` property? I'm not sure what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: bytw, text-overflow is meant for text :) the span coming in the way is not a big surprise somehow.

Comment: Yeah, I was aware of that in some way. But I was a bit unsettled, because I found nothing similar on Stack Overflow concerning my issue...

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that `max-width` is too big. Also, you should use relative length to have something scalable with your text. Here is the result with `5em`:

```css
.container {
  border        : 1px solid black;
  max-width     : 5em;
  overflow      : hidden;
  text-overflow : ellipsis;
  white-space   : nowrap;
}

.backgroundColor {
  background-color : green;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    Lorem ipsum
    <span class="backgroundColor">should not be visible</span>
</div>
```

If you can modify HTML, what you're trying to achieve looks like the tags [`details`](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_details.asp)/[`summary`](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_summary.asp):

```css
details {
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: green;
}

summary {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: white;
}

summary:after {
  content: " ...";
}
```

```html
<details>
    <summary>Lorem ipsum</summary>
    should not be visible
</details>
```

Comment: Your snippet doesn't work with another string, try "Lorem ips" for example

Comment: @YuriGor first one or second one?

Answer (score 0):

you can reset `display` of span to `inline-block` so it behaves as a single block/box/caracter. I won't try to span on a few lines and will be hidden as long as it has not enough room.

```css
.container {
  border: 1px solid black;
  max-width: 100px;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
.backgroundColor {
  background-color: green;
  display:inline-block
}
.aa {
 
  max-width: 200px;
  }
.bb {
  
  max-width: 240px;
  }
```

```html
<div class="container">
  Lorem ipsum
  <span class="backgroundColor">should not be visible</span>
</div>
<div class="container aa">
  Lorem ipsum
  <span class="backgroundColor">should not be visible</span>
</div>
<div class="container bb">
  Lorem ipsum
  <span class="backgroundColor">should not be visible</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the purpose of that span, so i am not sure is it acceptable for you to add some left margin to it, look here:

```css
.container {
  border        : 1px solid black;
  max-width     : 100px;
  overflow      : hidden;
  text-overflow : ellipsis;
  white-space   : nowrap;
}

.backgroundColor {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 10px;
  background-color : green;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    Lorem ipsumm
    <span class="backgroundColor">should not be visible</span>
</div>
```